# Where to find clear glass beer bottles?

Tags: bottling, kombucha

Can't seem to find any 12 oz clear glass beer bottles (without caps) online anywhere. Other ideas?

Comment: Probably because using clear bottles is such a bad idea.  Unless you store the in the dark, the beer will become lightstruck, also called "skunked".

Comment: What about Corona? That's a huge operation that uses exclusively clear bottles. Either way, I'm doing kombucha. The clear to is to make it obvious I'm not drinking beer at work ;)

Comment: Corona uses a specially processed hop extract that does not do that.  But knowing you're making kombucha makes a difference....no hops, no problem!

Comment: There are clear Grolsch type bottles on Amazon, however they are 16 oz. http://www.amazon.com/Chefs-Star-CASE-OF-12/dp/B00YB6D84Y/

Comment: Yeah and they have the EZ caps, which I don't want. Why is it so hard to find these? Thinking I may just use an amber bottle and create a "NOT BOOZE" sticker.

Comment: Mind if I ask why you are interested in clear bottles ?  They will hurt the shelf life of your beer by letting light in- resulting in skunky beer.

Comment: Fair question. I'm not brewing beer. I'm brewing kombucha. It's a marketing/branding decision, really, made in spite of some obvious drawbacks. Same thought process behind Corona beer, Hard Rock cider, and GT Kombucha, who all use clear glass bottles.

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to drink a lot of beer and recycle the bottles, then Newcastle Brown Ale comes in clear cap-able bottles.
Thats where my clear bottles come from.
Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Our local beer shop sells recycled bottles? Either that my local pub saves me bottles that normally get smashed and recycled so you could ask there?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what country you are in, but if you are in South Africa (or willing to pay shipping) here are some links:
Consol Glass: http://products.consol.co.za/products/alcoholic-beverages
Nampak: http://www.nampak.com/Downloads/beer.pdf