# Where can I get small glass bottles in San Francisco?

Tags: bottling

I'm looking to bottle cocktails in small glass bottles.

I've been looking online and most smaller bottles are either very expensive or have extremely pricy shipping (in most all cases, it comes to around $45/24 bottles (e.g. Amazon [has them](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0089WIAP8) for $46/24, Shore Container [has them](http://www.shorecontainer.com/187mlflintmini-champagneflatbottom.aspx) for $15 + $28 shipping).

One option is to buy something like [Fever Tree tonic water](http://amzn.com/B001XUO8AY), drink that, then reuse the bottles. I could also buy a 24 pack of Coronitas and reuse those bottles.

Any ideas on a source for bottles I could buy in San Francisco, a cheaper option online, or ideas for alternative sources of bottles like the Fever Tree/Coronitas idea?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not about brewing, possibly a marketing ploy.

Comment: Hey @Pepi, I have a pretty [significant history](http://stackexchange.com/users/1206692/maxgabriel) over the rest of the StackExchange network; I'm not a marketer. I can remove the links if that's a homebrew.stackexchange policy or something. While not about beer, the question is about bottling which is core to brewing, and the question could just as easily have been about bottling beer as cocktails. [Similar questions](http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/15857/where-to-find-clear-glass-beer-bottles?rq=1) exist on the rest of homebrew.stackexchange, as well.

Answer (score 1):

Rainbow coop has lots of different sized glass bottles.  13th & Folsom.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Mexican restaurants serve a drink which is a mix of a margarita and a small 7 oz. Corona. If you find one of those restaurants, maybe they would save the extras for you? Otherwise, check Chinatown for a supplier. those guys down there can get you pretty much anything.

Answer (score 0):

I would check with SF Brewcraft to see if they have anything or if they could place a special order for you.